# Why is the copy constructor being called for the construction of an empty unique_ptr vector?

Tags: c++, vector, copy-constructor

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

class A {
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>> vec;
public:
    virtual ~A() = 0;
};

A::~A() {}

class B : public A {
public:
    B() {}
};

int main () {
    B b = B();
    return 0;
}
```

Above is a minimal reproducible example. It does not compile, and the following error message is given:

```
me:~ $ g++ main2.cc
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/vector:62:0,
                 from main2.cc:1:
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_construct.h: In instantiation of ‘void std::_Construct(_T1*, _Args&& ...) [with _T1 = std::unique_ptr<int>; _Args = {const std::unique_ptr<int, std::default_delete<int> >&}]’:
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:83:18:   required from ‘static _ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_copy<_TrivialValueTypes>::__uninit_copy(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator) [with _InputIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const std::unique_ptr<int>*, std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int> > >; _ForwardIterator = std::unique_ptr<int>*; bool _TrivialValueTypes = false]’
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:134:15:   required from ‘_ForwardIterator std::uninitialized_copy(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator) [with _InputIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const std::unique_ptr<int>*, std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int> > >; _ForwardIterator = std::unique_ptr<int>*]’
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:289:37:   required from ‘_ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_copy_a(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator, std::allocator<_Tp>&) [with _InputIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const std::unique_ptr<int>*, std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int> > >; _ForwardIterator = std::unique_ptr<int>*; _Tp = std::unique_ptr<int>]’
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_vector.h:331:31:   required from ‘std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::vector(const std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>&) [with _Tp = std::unique_ptr<int>; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::unique_ptr<int> >]’
main2.cc:5:7:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_construct.h:75:7: error: use of deleted function ‘std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&) [with _Tp = int; _Dp = std::default_delete<int>]’
     { ::new(static_cast<void*>(__p)) _T1(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/memory:80:0,
                 from main2.cc:2:
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/unique_ptr.h:388:7: note: declared here
       unique_ptr(const unique_ptr&) = delete;
       ^~~~~~~~~~
```

What it all seems like is that the copy constructor for the `unique_ptr` is being called somewhere.

But I have no idea why it would be called at all. When a vector is initialized, it has size 0, right? Under that assumption, no `unique_ptr` should be constructed.

What is the source of my compilation error?

Comment: For your version of `g++ main2.cc` what is the default C++ (or GNU C++ variant) standard being used?

Comment: @Eljay [C++17 support was experimental/draft in GCC 7](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-7/changes.html), so it's not that.

Comment: `A::~A() {}` - *Don't* do that. You are pessimising your code. By making the destructor user defined (even if empty), you are ensuring that it can no longer be *trivial*. Use `~A() = default;` in the declaration, instead.

Comment: Don't write it at all; it's pointless.

Comment: @Eljay I usually compile with `g++ -std=c++14 main2.cc`. The same error is being given here. I actually don't know how to check what the default g++ variant is for me

Comment: @Lightness - agreed.

Comment: @JesperJuhl The reason I did this is that my class was taught you should only be inheriting from abstract classes. An abstract class has at least one pure virtual function. Usually if nothing else works, a destructor is made pure virtual instead

Comment: Why are you making ~A pure virtual, and then implement it? Second it shouldn't not be virtual or pure virtual, its not deriving from anything, only derived classes make their destructors virtual

Comment: @OmidCompSCI Pure virtual destructors *must* be implemented. And the *base* destructor must be virtual, not the derived once...

Comment: @OmidCompSCI Everything you just said is incorrect, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`B b = B()` is a copy-initialisation and, until C++17, required that the copy be valid (even if it ended up being elided).

Even though the size of the vector in that copy is zero, that is not something that can be statically known by the innards of the copy machinery during compile-time. So, the code to make it work must be "known" during compilation, so that it is available at runtime if needed.

You probably meant just a normal declaration: `B b;`.

The original approach would actually have been enough if your class were trivially-moveable (because a `unique_ptr` can be moved), but by giving it a user-declared destructor you pessimised it. Unless you actually have a strong reason to want this class to be polymorphic, don't do that. Use `= default` or just omit the destructor entirely; it's not doing anything useful.

Comment: Still, I confess to being a little surprised that moveability isn't enough

Comment: It is not movable because of the user-declared destructor.

Comment: @uneven_mark I don't get it. Why is it true that making a user defined destructor gets rid of the default move constructor? Why does it compromise the "trivial moveability" of `unique_ptr`?

Comment: @herophant There are extant questions about that you can find

Comment: @herophant Declaring any destructor manually inhibits the implicit declaration of the move constructor. That is just a rule of the language. `B b = B()` would normally use the move constructor if it was available. But because it isn't here, it falls back to copy construction which doesn't work with `std::unique_ptr`. You can default the move constructor explicitly (`A(A&&) = default;`) to get back the default behavior you would have had without user-declared destructor, but evaluate first whether you really need the class to be polymorphic and abstract.

Comment: @uneven_mark I most certainly need it to be polymorphic, there's multiple things that are inheriting from it in my actual program. I suppose abstractness is not needed though, although it was often said in my class that it was for any polymorphic classes (better design or something). I'll just get rid of the destructor delclaration/implementation for now.

Comment: @herophant Being inheritable and being polymorphic are two different things. I _think_ by "abstractness" you mean the latter. Anyway, this is largely tangential, but if you're interested in this you should look into `noexcept`

Comment: @herophant The class only needs to be polymorphic if you are going to use it polymorphically (i.e. pointers or references to the base class type to point to objects of derived type). This is often not the case. You can always inherit from a class, it doesn't need to be polymorphic to do that.

Comment: @uneven_mark Less tangentially, deleting `A::~A() {}` and also making it `virtual ~A() = default` still gives the same error. I need the `virtual` since I want any references or pointers of type `A` to also call the subclass destructor.

Comment: @herophant Yes, it doesn't matter what kind of destructor you declare for the movability issue. Then your only solution is to explicitly default the move constructor (and move assignment operator) as I mentioned: `A(A&&) = default; A& operator=(A&&) = default;`.